# How to populate json array within a loop

Tags: java, json

I want to get data from table and populate that data into an array using json object.

I have done hardcoded example which is working fine but now I want to populate data using a loop. But using loop is casuing overlapping data. Means at the end only 1 line is there in output.

```
JSONObject items = new JSONObject();
JSONArray itemlines = new JSONArray();

Statement getLines = dbconnection.createStatement();
ResultSet LinesRS = getLines.executeQuery("SELECT 
b.line_number,b.ordered_item,b.description,b.line_quantity,
"(SELECT order_quantity_uom FROM oe_order_lines_all WHERE line_id = 
b.line_id) uom\n" +
"FROM rocell.xrcl_ns_int_quotation_details b WHERE b.header_id = 
"+getQuotationsRS.getString(1));
         while(LinesRS.next())
         {
           items.put("lineNo", LinesRS.getString(1));
           items.put("itemCode", LinesRS.getString(2));
           items.put("itemDesc", LinesRS.getString(3));
           items.put("qty", LinesRS.getString(4));
           items.put("unit", LinesRS.getString(22)); 
           itemlines.put(items);
         }



record.put("items", itemlines);

I want output like below

"items": [ { "lineNo": 1, 
             "itemCode": "IT001", 
             "itemDesc": "Bottle", 
             "qty": "3",
             "unit":"EA"},
           { "lineNo": 2, 
             "itemCode": "IT002", 
             "itemDesc": "Flask", 
             "qty": "2",
             "unit":"EA"}
         ]
```

Comment: You need to initialize `items` for each row in your result set. So for each iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray itemlines = new JSONArray();

Statement getLines = dbconnection.createStatement();
ResultSet LinesRS = getLines.executeQuery("SELECT 
b.line_number,b.ordered_item,b.description,b.line_quantity,
"(SELECT order_quantity_uom FROM oe_order_lines_all WHERE line_id = 
b.line_id) uom\n" +
"FROM rocell.xrcl_ns_int_quotation_details b WHERE b.header_id = 
"+getQuotationsRS.getString(1));
         while(LinesRS.next())
         { //every time this JSONObject items  is init and put into itemlines
           JSONObject items = new JSONObject();
           items.put("lineNo", LinesRS.getString(1));
           items.put("itemCode", LinesRS.getString(2));
           items.put("itemDesc", LinesRS.getString(3));
           items.put("qty", LinesRS.getString(4));
           items.put("unit", LinesRS.getString(22)); 
           itemlines.put(items);
         }



record.put("items", itemlines);
```